# Re-open request

Tags: support, reopen-request

I asked this question: [Switching between non-suspended apps (with alt-tab?)](https://superuser.com/q/491562/85165) which got closed as duplicate.

The orignal question though only details how to switch applications, not now to switch between a list that doesn't include suspended ones.

I'm happy for the answer to my question to be "It's not possible", but I don't feel the question should be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing and doesn't state clearly what exactly you want, like you have done so here. For future cases I suggest you re-write the post before prompting to reopen. In this case however there is only a set way to switch between apps no matter their state thus making the dupe a definitive answer. Any answers to your post are going to be the same.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to make the orignal question more clear. Like I say, I'm happy for the answer to be "It's not possible". I think an explicit answer to my question is better than one implied by my question being closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett you're question being closed as a duplicate implicitly implies that the answer is the same.  You use the same way to switch between apps in Windows 8 no matter the actual 'state' they're in unless they're closed then they're not available through fast switching methods.  Answering this with "No" provides no more detail than that.

Comment: Ok, I can see where you (and commenters on the orignal question) are coming from. Personally I still think an answer (maybe with a link to the answer on the other question) would be more useful, particularly to people not familiar to SU or the SE network.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett You question links to the duplicate question, and therefore the answers.